# ES6: fire React function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is the code:

```
class Seismo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      news: ""
    }
    this.updateNews = this.updateNews.bind(this)
  }

  updateNews = () => {
    console.log('test')
  }
```

What I am trying to do is to fire the `updateNews` code from `render`:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Button 
          type="primary"
          onClick={async () => {
              this.updateNews // This is what I am trying to fire!
          }
      >TEST</Button>
```

But keep getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: this.updateNews is not a function

Comment: Is the code in this question the same as the code you're working with? The code here would cause a syntax error

Comment: Either way, [here's a working example of what it looks like you want to do.](https://codesandbox.io/s/3yxvnlvnyq) Maybe A/B it with your code, see what's different, and fix it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not calling the functuion

```
      <Button 
          type="primary"
          onClick={async () => {
              this.updateNews() // This is what I am trying to fire!
          }
      >TEST</Button>
```

Note:
You do need to bind because you use arrow function.

Comment: Worked. Thanks!

Comment: *don't* need to bind

Comment: Yes, we only bind regular functions because  it loses its binding to the this context which is in our case the react class. In case of arrow function which does not have a this context it looks for the this in the upper scope which is the class so there is no need for binding